# React.js, uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token <

Tags: reactjs

This was working a moment ago, now it's not! tried to retrace my steps and fix the error but no luck. Any insight?

Here is a link to the git hub repo:
https://github.com/malexanders/react-toolbox-example

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you see when you browse to `http://0.0.0.0:8080/react-toolbox.css`?  It looks like it's returning an html page.  You may have accidentally changed your web dev server configuration.

Comment: added update with image that shows the result

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you spot the syntax error below?

```
  handleChange((name, value){
    this.setState(
        {name: value}
    );
  };
```

This is was the problem! manifested in an totally unexpected way. change it to this:

```
  handleChange(name, value){
    this.setState(
        {name: value}
    );
  };
```

And, Voila!

Comment: Install eslint to help with these types of problems. :)